# How to make installed software visit the folder I created in root path?

Tags: permissions

I met a problem, that installed SQLite browser can not load file from the folder I created from root path.

e.g. I created a folder `/workspace` from the root path:  ( in the bottom of the list )

```
$ cd / 
$ ls -al 
drwxr-xr-x  25 root  root       4096 Mar 31 11:18 ./
drwxr-xr-x  25 root  root       4096 Mar 31 11:18 ../
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  root       4096 Apr  3 16:15 bin/
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  root       4096 Mar  3 06:00 boot/
drwxrwxr-x   2 root  root       4096 Mar  3 05:58 cdrom/
drwxr-xr-x  18 root  root       4220 Apr 16 09:15 dev/
drwxr-xr-x 130 root  root      12288 Apr 16 10:17 etc/
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  root       4096 Mar  3 05:58 home/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root  root         33 Mar  3 05:59 initrd.img -> boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-29-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root  root         33 Mar  3 05:57 initrd.img.old -> boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-29-generic
drwxr-xr-x  21 root  root       4096 Mar  3 05:59 lib/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  root       4096 Jul 25  2018 lib64/
drwx------   2 root  root      16384 Mar  3 13:57 lost+found/
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  root       4096 Jul 25  2018 media/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  root       4096 Jul 25  2018 mnt/
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  root       4096 Mar  3 08:25 opt/
dr-xr-xr-x 339 root  root          0 Apr 10 10:52 proc/
drwx------   5 root  root       4096 Mar 31 14:52 root/
drwxr-xr-x  30 root  root        860 Apr 16 05:52 run/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  root      12288 Apr  3 16:15 sbin/
drwxr-xr-x  20 root  root       4096 Apr 16 09:15 snap/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  root       4096 Jul 25  2018 srv/
-rw-------   1 root  root  993244160 Mar  3 13:57 swapfile
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root  root          0 Apr 16 09:08 sys/
drwxrwxrwt  31 root  root       4096 Apr 16 12:32 tmp/
drwxr-xr-x  10 root  root       4096 Jul 25  2018 usr/
drwxr-xr-x  14 root  root       4096 Jul 25  2018 var/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root  root         30 Mar  3 05:59 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-29-generic
drwxr-xr-x   9 siwei siwei      4096 Apr 14 11:36 workspace/
```

and I installed sqlitebrowser via Ubuntu software center:

[image]

However, when I want to open a `.db` file under `/workspace` folder, the path could not be seen under `sqlitebrowser`:

[image]

I have checked that I gave permissions to this program, and restart my PC, still not works.

[image]

could anyone gives me a clue? thanks a lot!

My environment:  Ubuntu 18.04  LTS,

Comment: Looks like a SQLite Snap. Snaps can only access your home directory. That's part of their built-in sandboxing. They cannot access the rest of the filesystem, nor see random files outside /home/$YOU, regardless of the file's owner. Move your /workspace to within your home directory.

Comment: Yes, it's a Snap version. Is there any solution that I don't need to move my `/workspace` folder? such as another non-Snap version ?

Comment: Of course there is. Return to Ubuntu Software to do it. Uninstall the snap, then install the deb. Pay close attention to the "Source:" field so you can tell the difference between the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @user535733 's comment, I got the root cause: the software I installed is a `snap version` , see the picture below

[image]

solution:

1. move my project file ( or sqlite file ) to the origin folder ( e.g. user home folder ) and continue to use the `snap version`.
2. uninstall the snap version from "software center", and then re-install the `normal version`.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:linuxgndu/sqlitebrowser-testing
$ sudo apt update
$ apt install sqlitebrowser
```